# What is the proper way to trigger on-demand TCP message(s) to reconnectable, non-sharable Netty pipeline?

Tags: sockets, tcp, netty, nio

I have a Netty 4.x TCP client application with a reconnect listener, and I cannot think of a way to implement a trigger (HTTP, MQ, etc.) that will write to the socket channel.

So far, I've tried to add a `write(ByteBuf msg)` to my `ChannelInboundHandler`, by following [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928898/sending-message-with-external-call-in-netty-socket-programming?rq=1), but with my reconnect listener, I get the following exception upon reconnect:

```
... is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.
```

I am new to Netty, so I'm not sure if perhaps a user event trigger could solve this.

Reconnection code:

```java
if (!future.isSuccess()) {
    future.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> {
        bootstrap.connect().addListener(this);
    }, reconnectDelayTimeNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} else {
    future.channel().closeFuture().addListener((ChannelFuture cf) -> {
        bootstrap.connect().addListener(this);
    });
}
```

Bootstrap code:

```java
final MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
final EventLoopGroup requestGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
final Bootstrap requestBootstrap = new Bootstrap()
        .group(requestGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .remoteAddress("localhost", 9999)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
requestBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(final SocketChannel ch) {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(myHandler);
    }
});
```

In order to be able to use the `write(ByteBuf msg)` method from my handler, the handler needs to have a reference outside of `ChannelInitializer`.

I expect to be able to send a message to the pipeline, non-sharable handler, etc. from a trigger (HTTP, MQ, etc.).

At the moment, I am getting the following exception:

```
... is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your `MyHandler` as sharable by annotating it with `@Sharable` or overriding the `isSharable()` method. That said you need to ensure the handler is thread-safe in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately my handlers are stateful, so I essentially need to handle three cases: 1. The connection must be reconnectable, 2. The pipeline can consist of stateful handlers, 3. There needs to be a way to trigger messages to the connections from outside of the pipeline.